# C# take a substring of a string

Tags: c#, string, substring

I am taking a line from a file only if that file doen't have a specific pattern.. and  i want to take from that line the last 3 chars... my code is:

```
        while (!line.Contains(pattern))
        {
             String num = line.Substring((line.Length - 3), (line.Length - 2));
             System.Console.WriteLine(num);
        }
```

but i get an error..

> Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
>   Parameter name: length

why i get that? i am starting the new string 3 chars before the end of the line and i stop 2 chars before.. :\

Comment: Presumably your string is less than 3 characters long.

Comment: Starting 3 chars before, stopping 2 chars before makes 1 character. Do you want 3 characters or 1 character?

Comment: How long is your line? If you don't check the length before substring you will certainly create issues.

Comment: i dont know the lines length cause it is not the same all the times... i just want the last 3 chars...

Comment: Just tossing this out, but there's probably a nifty RegEx way to just parse all the lines at once and match the last 3 chars on each line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Substring takes an offset and then a number of characters to return:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa904308%28v=VS.71%29.aspx

So:

```
String num = line.Substring((line.Length - 3), 3);
```

This of course assumes that line.Length > 3.  You could check with:

```
String num = (line.Length < 3) ? line : line.Substring((line.Length - 3), 3);
```

Comment: +1 - this Q was always going to attract a flood of answers but you got in there first ;-)  Some other answers seem to think that 4 should be subtracted from the length, which is clearly incorrect.

Comment: That's incorrect. Arrays are indexed starting from 0, so there is no char which index is `line.Length`

Comment: @rotman, think of a string with length 3. If I take length -3 then I get zero which is the first character.

Comment: @rotman: could you than please give an example when this code fails?

Comment: Yea when I was writing my answer, I almost typed `- 4` and actually had to draw out the array on paper to make sure I was right :)

Answer (score 2):

Second argument of `Substring` is how many chars it have to take starting from first argument. It should just look like that:
`String num = line.Substring(line.Length - 3, 3);`

Comment: Ah, the old no-comment answer edit.  So now I have to comment on my comment so I don't look like an idiot.  Thank you for changing the -4 to a -3.

Comment: My mistake once again. Sorry mate, got to remember about that.

Answer (score 1):

This is dangerous. What if the length of the line is < 3? You should probably check this otherwise you will get an exception.

In addition you should use the substring method as depicted [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) :

```
String num = line.Substring((line.Length - 3), 3);
```

Comment: @AdamRalph: What a finely worded and insightful comment.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you try to get more characters then your array have.

Extensions are best for problems like this one ;) Mine have some dirty name but everyone know what it would do - this is exception safe substring:

```
public static string SubstringNoLongerThenSource(this string source, int startIndex, int maxLength)
{
    return source.Substring(startIndex, Math.Min(source.Length - startIndex, maxLength));
}
```

So in your exact problem it should be like that:

```
String num = line.SubstringNoLongerThenSource((line.Length - 3), 3);
System.Console.WriteLine(num);
```

So *num* will have max 3 letters if the string you provide to function have enough letters :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String num = line.Substring(line.Length - 3)
```

Comment: Explaining your snippet would be much more helpful.

Comment: If you specify only the starting position of the substring, the substring is taken as a whole after it.
Since this case must be followed by last three letters, (Length-3) is sufficient to specify.

Answer (score -1):

This is happening because the last parameter of Substring() should be the length of the string to extract.

In your case it should be 3

, and not `line.Length - 2`

The first parameter should also be:

`line.Length - 3`

Comment: You're correct, no idea why I put that. I have edited my answer.