# Substring is not working as expected if length is greater than length of String

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I know *if/else* works, but I needed an alternative.

I am using

```
B = String.Concat(A.Substring(0, 40));
```

to capture the first 40 characters of a value.

If the value at `A` is more than `40`, `B` is able to capture, but if the value of `A` is less than `40`, there is no value being captured at `B`.

Comment: Why are you calling `String.Concat` with a single input?

Comment: What is the purpose of `String.Concat()`? Ypu normally use it to join two strings together, but you are only passing in one String?

Comment: _"but if the [length of the] value of A is less than 40, there is no value being captured at B."_ - probably because an exception occurred.

Comment: There is no value "being" captured, because in that case `Substring` will throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` (message "Index and length must refer to a location within the string."). More code/context is required to judge further.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? it seems that whatever it is you are doing it the wrong way...

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# take a substring of a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097640/c-sharp-take-a-substring-of-a-string)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*String.Concat* does not serve your purpose here. You should rather do the following:

```
if(A.Length > 40)
    B = A.Substring(0, 40);
else
    B = A;
```

Answer (score 76):

A quick one line would be:

```
  B = A?.Length > 40 ? A.Substring(0, 40) : A;
```

which only implements the substring when the length is more than 40.
For the sake of redundancy, 40 would preferably be a variable of course. The use of '?.' prevents errors when 'A' is null.
As ean5533 mentioned `A.Substring(0, Math.Min(40, A.Length))` can also be used. Same outcome, prevents the use of '40' twice, but will always invoke the substring function (not that that matters in this day of age)

For ease of use, an extension method can be created

```
public static string Truncate(this string value, int MaxLength) => value?.Length > MaxLength? value.Substring(0, MaxLength) : value;
```

Comment: Similar quick and dirty: `A.Substring(0, Math.Min(40, A.Length))`

Comment: Quick for sure, but why should it be dirty :) ?

Comment: @benjer: I know that feeling, stackoverflow is the busiest forum on the web :)

Comment: @PaoloTedesco , perhaps not dirty, but had to put down something :p

Comment: @ean5533 : that was my first impulse as well, but that would cause a possible unnecessary call to substring (yeah I know, micromanagement talk :D )

Comment: @Me.Name Oh yeah, that moment when you know you must put "and something" afterwards... Precious times, I tell you... That's life. It's the little things, really... "Quick and dirty", ugh, that is brilliant... Little things...

Comment: not working emlMessage.cs(198,9): error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement,
        and new object expressions can be used as a statement. Actually the database has 40 length.

Comment: What is the complete code?  To be used it must be assigned to a variable (or result) as in :   B = A.Length > 40 ? A.Substring(0, 40) : A;

Comment: @ean5533 Best "answer".  Most clearly expresses intent.

Comment: Though make ean5533's [an extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx), and we're lots closer to Step 3, Profit.

Comment: @ean5533 solution is better and simple .. A.Substring(0, Math.Min(40, A.Length))

Comment: Extension method is already there on my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30692581/1696967 :)

Comment: Can you [explain](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) your answer, please? E.g., it could include references to the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:). And what the disadvantage is. (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Comment: But why the heck does Substring not do the Math.Min itself on the end parameter. Makes no sense that you need to provide this a million times all over!

Answer (score 28):

Create an extension for it... Call it Truncate or Left, or whatever.

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static string Truncate(this string s, int length)
    {
        if(s.Length > length) 
            return s.Substring(0, length);
        return s;
    }
}
```

Then you can simply call it like so:

```
string B = A.Truncate(40);
```

Also note that you don't have to make it an extension method, although it would be cleaner.

In your StringTool class:

```
public static string Truncate(string value, int length)
{
    if(value.Length > length) 
        return value.Substring(0, length);
    return value;
}
```

And to call it:

```
string B = StringTool.Truncate(A, 40);
```

Comment: truncate would be the right fix, there is already a very huge number of if/elses in the code.

Comment: @Lordlebu - Why are you trying to reduce the number of if/else statements exactly?

Comment: ok one error - emlMessage.cs(198,35): error CS0117: 'string' does not contain a definition for
        'Truncate', I tried StringTool, still doesnot work

Comment: err... probably needs to be static.

Answer (score 22):

use below code to substring

```
B = String.padright(40).Substring(0, 40))
```

Comment: Love this solution actually

Comment: But after the text there are many spaces. You should use this:
`B = String.padright(40, '\0').Substring(0, 40))`

Comment: Simple and elegant, plus can be used inline without additional method

Comment: Trim the result to get rid of extra spaces. `"1234".PadRight(40).Substring(0, 40).TrimEnd()`

Comment: This performs unnecessary string allocations, by first creating a string with more spaces, and then trimming those spaces off. It's more efficient to just perform the length check up front.

Answer (score 17):

Extensions are best for problems like this one ;)

Mine have some dirty name, but everyone knows what it would do - this is an exception-safe substring:

```
public static string SubstringNoLongerThanSource(this string source, int startIndex, int maxLength)
{
    return source.Substring(startIndex, Math.Min(source.Length - startIndex, maxLength));
}
```

Comment: What makes it exception-safe? Is it in contrast to some other answers?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Because this method is checking if end index is not bigger than string length so no ArgumentOutOfRangeException will be thrown

Answer (score 9):

```
B = string.Concat(A.Substring(0, Math.Min(40, A.Length)));
```

Comment: Yes! I prefer Math.Min() over a ternary expression or if/else; keeps the check within the space of the parameter, rather than cluttering things outside of it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Left](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y050k1wb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) from `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings`.

```
B = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Left(A, 40);
```

I don't know why you want to use `Concat`, anyway.

Comment: @Ramhound In which way exactly will this fail? Did you even test it? I don't think you know what `Left` does.

Comment: Using `Left` is even considered bad practice in VB.NET, let alone importing the VB-legacy namespace into C# to use it there...

Comment: @dkson - Fine.  I took ANOTHER look at the method.  If length is longer then the length of the string the entire string is returned.  I still maintain this is bad practice and thus a bad answer so going to maintain my down vote.

Comment: @Ramhound Fine. You took another look at the method. If length is longer then the length of the string the entire string is returned. Otherwise, the string is truncated to the given length. That's exactly what the questioner asked for, and that's what the accepted answer does. So basically you are saying it is bad practice to use a well-tested, well-known and well-documented method of the .Net framework and you should instead reinvent the wheel and write a method that does the exact same thing.

Comment: @minitech Why should this be bad practice? So you're not allowed to use methods in C# if there's 'VisualBasic' in the namespace? What's the problem?

Comment: @user1443957: It's not specific to C#; I wouldn't use those methods in VB.NET, either. They're leftovers from VB6 and they look ugly and you shouldn't use them. It's akin to still checking for and using `document.all` in JavaScript, if that happens to be your area of expertise.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using Left( ).  If it bothers you, make a string extension called Left( ).

Answer (score 4):

Another method using Take

```
B = new string(A.Take(40).ToArray())
```

Or extension method

```
public static string Left(this string value, int count)
{
    return new string(value.Take(count).ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Can you link to documentation (non-naked link)?

Answer (score 0):

**Just use**:

```
var B = A.Substring(0, Math.Min(A.Length, 40));
```