# Substring will not work if the string is too short

Tags: c#, regex, substring

I have a telephone number that a person types into our program.  We do not validate numbers on the user side (don't ask...). So what I did was used RegEx to strip all foreign characters and run a comparison with another RegEx (this is what the boss wants).

Once I have created a plain string for this number, I manually put hyphens into the string so our database can use it for comparison.

Unfortunately, when the user places a letter in the string, the string is shortened by one character, making my Substring throw an error. How would you rewrite this code (I'm thinking "if" statement but being that I'm fairly new to this and I don't want to inflate the code, I don't really trust myself at this point.)

```
telephone = Regex.Replace(telephone, "[^0-9.]", "");

StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

sb.Append(telephone.Substring(0, 3) 
          + "-" + telephone.Substring(3, 3) 
          + "-" + telephone.Substring(6, 4));

return sb.ToString();
```

I have checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032394/substring-not-working-as-expected-if-length-greater-than-length-of-string) and it wasn't what I was looking for.

UPDATE:

Expected result - Will still run with less than 10 numbers (including less than 4 or 3 numbers).  Our table will still be populated with those options.  We have other filtering on the panel, so the panel won't be big based off of 3-digit number

The user will just get a larger list (this is based off of company protocol).
When I run it currently, the program just hangs with no updates to our panel.  I have to physically restart the debugger from VS because there's no way to get out of our program.

Answer:

It was a mix of answers.  I checked the one that I used for the actual telephone number itself:

```
telephone = Regex.Replace(telephone, "[^0-9.]", "");
if (telephone.Length > 3)
telephone = telephone.Insert(3, "-");
if (telephone.Length > 7)
telephone = telephone.Insert(7, "-");
return telephone;
```

Then I had to adjust the stored procedure to work correctly:

```
WHERE OfficePhone LIKE '%" +  @newPhone  + "%' ";
```

Thank you all for the help!

Comment: So what do you want it to *do* with shorter text? Sample input, expected output, and what you've tried would all help...

Comment: Your update ("will still run") doesn't answer the questions. What should _the code do to the `telephone` string_ if it is shorter than the given amount of characters?

Comment: There is no point in using a `StringBuilder` if you're just going to concatenate the strings that you pass into one call of `Append`.

Comment: Maybe you should show how you are using the values to do filtering as it sounds like your problem exists in the part that filters.

Comment: I'm using the phone number in a Stored Procedure.  Our database needs to have those hyphens to complete the search.

Comment: You're still not answering the questions. It cannot add all hyphens if the input is, say, `123456`. Should it then become `123-456`, or should it stay `123456`? Show example input and output covering all cases. By then I'm sure you can figure out how to do that using the hints given in the answers.

Comment: @KevinFischer Can you show us the stored procedure?  It's starting to sound like you have SQL that is taking a very long time to run.

Comment: @juharr It's a legacy code stored procedure that does take a ton of time to run.  Sadly, I wasn't allocated to do that just yet.  That's on the to-do list months down the road.  I was told to make it work.  I can make it more efficient later.

Comment: So if you are comparing these value to other phone numbers then would an input of say "1234" have to match "123-456-7890" and "555-123-4567"?

Comment: @KevinFischer Knowing how the stored procedure uses these values might help determine what you need, but my gut tells me the stored procedure might have to change for this to work.  In general I'm assuming it does something along the line of `where phoneNumber like '%' + filterNumber + '%'`

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes, it should be 123-456.  Unfortunately, I can't show examples because the program gets hung up on the code for the Substring error.  I'll adjust the code, and remove the StringBuilder and see how that works.

Comment: @juharr It would actually run like this:
123456 would be the input.  The SP will run it as 123-456xxxx where 123 would be the area code.  I don't really feel comfortable sharing the SP being the fact that this is my second week on the job and I don't know what's considered sensitive and what isn't.

Comment: WHERE OfficePhone = @newPhone.  That's all in the WHERE clause.

Comment: That's an exact match, and unless you have partial phone numbers in your DB then I don't see how you can match on partials.

Comment: You're right.  I'll have to confirm with Boss and see what she wants.  Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i would avoid StringBuilder here. This approach won't throw a ArgumentOutOfRangeException and it will insert a `-` in case of your number has the necessary length.

```
telephone = Regex.Replace(telephone, "[^0-9.]", "");
if (telephone.Length > 3)
    telephone  = telephone.Insert(3, "-");
if (telephone.Length > 7)
    telephone  = telephone.Insert(7, "-");

return telephone;
```

Comment: Would you also explain why you wouldn't use StringBuilder?

Comment: @ KevinFischer StringBuilder makes sence when you concatenate a lot of data to have a advantage in performance. In this case you just have a string of 10 characters - any comments about by approach?

Answer (score 4):

You didn't tell what the code should do if the cleaned up string doesn't match the expected length.

It seems like you expect a cleaned number to be 10 characters long (6 + 4). Then you can fix it for example by throwing an exception:

```
telephone = Regex.Replace(telephone, "[^0-9.]", "");
if (telephone.Length != 10)
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Phone number length incorrect");
}
```

And there's not really any use for a stringbuilder here.

Comment: string.Format often looks cleaner : `string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", telephone.Substring(0, 3), telephone.Substring(3, 3), telephone.Substring(6, 4));`

Comment: I don't really want it to throw the exception.  I still want it to run with less than 10 numbers.

Comment: I still want it to populate our form/filter.  I updated my original question.  Hopefully that will clear it up